# Display webpage in iframe dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I want an input field with a submit button and a separate iframe where I can display a website made up from the input field. I have tried all sorts of things but nothing works. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve that. The text input field is a key to the page I want to display.  What I want to do is to define an iframe with a page from my website and when the user enters a code in the text box, the iframe should display another page from my website. I want to run everything on my PC and nothing on the server. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
<style>
  #boxes {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    width: 145%;
  }

div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0px;
}

#column0 {
  width: 5.9%;
}

#column1 {
  width:29.4%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:white;
  display: grid;
  height: 80vh;
  place-items: start;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>

<script>

  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `

    <main id="boxes">
    <div id="column0">
      <h4></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="column1">
      <input id="pageId" name="pageId" type="text" required minlength="1" 
      maxlength="4" pattern="[a-z0-9]+">
      <button id="pageIdBtn">Page ID</button>
    </div>
</main>
`;

var x = document.getElementById("pageIdBtn");
x.addEventListener("click", pageIdFunction);

function pageIdFunction() {
  var pageIdToInvoke = document.getElementById("pageId").value;
  var myPage = "mywebsite/" + pageIdToInvoke;
  var el = document.getElementById('userPage');
  el.src = myPage;
};

</script>

<iframe name="userPage" src="mywebsite/home" style="width:1500px; height: 
750px;">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample code.

Comment: Have added my code that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
$('input#url').on('propertychange paste keyup',function(){
  
  var url = this.value;
  $('#frame').attr('src', url);
  
});
```

```css
iframe {
  position:fixed; 
  top:5; 
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  right:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:90%; 
  border:none; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>display-webpage-in-iframe-dynamically</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="https://">
  
<iframe src="" id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If this helps please Up vote and mark as answer

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag in this poorly asked question

Comment: Well...should i delete my answer?

Comment: The above code snippet didn't work when copied and pasted into an html page

Comment: Worlks perfect for me. Press the blue button that says "Run code snippet". Also do you have this in your `head`? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run the above snippet and enter a valid website, it does not load the site in the iframe for me.

Comment: Working perfect for me like i said before. Can you show me exactly how you placed this code in?

Comment: I copied your code, put the iframe { position etc} between style tags between the body tags and the jquery code between script tags.in the head. Created a file with ,html extention on my PC and ran that. It comes up with the text field but when I enter anything in it, it does not open up the website.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work when you run it on your pc alone. You might need cloud hosting. please check out a codepen i made https://codepen.io/Benjamin-Dover/pen/abBqKvR. Idk tbh im not to good with this kind of stuff as i am a new programmer. I'm 15 and im sure almost everyone else here is smarter than me. And unlike most i dont have a pc anymore lol. I code off my school chromebook but it's been challenging since they blocked repl.it and glitch.com. But its cool. I'm still getting around. Anyway, sorry if i ddint help but please upvote my answer as i really need the 10 repl. Thx!